# Ms-access row data in vb array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

How can I get MS-Access data in the array?

I tried this:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim farmers() As String = {}
sql = "SELECT * FROM users"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
If Not reader.HasRows Then
    'nothing
ElseIf reader.HasRows Then
   Do While reader.Read
      farmers(i) = CStr(reader.Item(1))
      i += 1
   Loop
End If

For Each element As String In farmers
    MsgBox(element)
Next
```

It shows an error:

[image]

My `MS-Access` Database table is:

`users`

```
____________________________
|  ID |  Number    |  Name |
| 1   |  10        |  John |
| 2   |  15        |  Joe  |
| 3   |  7         | User3 |
```

and I want those `10 15 7` in array.

How can I get that? Or any other methods?

Any help is appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Your array has no dimension, you have to ReDim the array to contain all elements returned by the query
Something like :

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim farmers() As String = {}
sql = "SELECT * FROM users"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
If Not reader.HasRows Then
    'nothing
ElseIf reader.HasRows Then
   '-->> Add this line 
   ReDim(farmers,reader.rows.count)

   Do While reader.Read
      farmers(i) = CStr(reader.Item(1))
      i += 1
   Loop
End If

For Each element As String In farmers
    MsgBox(element)
Next
```

Comment: Error found in `ReDim` code. Can you help me by providing valid code? Please.
Because I'm a beginner in VB.

Comment: Just press F1 on the ReDim word and you will get the help you need.

Comment: Error in `reader.rows.count`. It did not count rows. How can I count ?

Comment: Well, @PradipDhakal the above comment applies here too :-)